# How to set disableLayout in zend framwork 1.12.19?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to zend framework 1.12.19, and now I am going to generate an excel file. I completed the code for that. in between I need to set layout to no layout.

I have written above lines to do that. But it is not working and it is giving me some errors.

```
 set_time_limit( 0 );

        $filename = '../data/uploaded-files/excel-uploaded/FILE.xls';
        $realPath = realpath( $filename );
        if ( false === $realPath )
        {
            touch( $filename );
            chmod( $filename, 0777 );
        }

        $filename = realpath( $filename );
        $handle = fopen( $filename, "w" );
        $finalData = array();
        $data = array
                    (
                        array("Volvo",22,18),
                        array("BMW",15,13),
                        array("Saab",5,2),
                        array("Land Rover",17,15)
                    );

        foreach ( $data AS $row )
        {

            $finalData[] = array(
                utf8_decode( $row[0] ), // For chars with accents.
                utf8_decode( $row[1] ),
                utf8_decode( $row[2] ),
            );
        }
        foreach ( $finalData AS $finalRow )
        {
            fputcsv( $handle, $finalRow, "\t" );
        }
        fclose( $handle );
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
        $this->getResponse()->setRawHeader( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8" )
            ->setRawHeader( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=otros-fondos.xls" )
            ->setRawHeader( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" )
            ->setRawHeader( "Expires: 0" )
            ->setRawHeader( "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" )
            ->setRawHeader( "Pragma: public" )
            ->setRawHeader( "Content-Length: " . filesize( $filename ) )
            ->sendResponse();
        readfile( $filename ); exit();
```

Error:
**Action Helper by name Layout not found**

Comment: It would help if you could show us a bit more code, for instance the entire action of your controller. Also, there is no ZF 1.2. Check `Zend/Version.php` for the actual version of the framework you are using.

Comment: Sorry, typo, its v1.12.19

Comment: I updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a small difference to your code but this is what you can try to do in your action:

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

The layout helper may need the parentheses.

**edit**

Since it looks like the plugin cannot be found: Are you sure it is present in `Zend/Layout/Controller/Action/Helper/Layout.php` and it is being autoloaded?

What are the contents of your application.ini?

Comment: I think so.

require_once ('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
require_once ('../../library/ZendFramework-1.12.19/library/Zend/Layout/Controller/Action/Helper/Layout.php');

Comment: Can you maybe post the entire controller? Maybe I can spot something for you. Also, what are the contents of `application.ini`?

Comment: I cann't put entire, but it is same as https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nebiros/288725/raw/c7568aea6ac7a873f25a06e0dc199e720fc9a616/IndexController.php